# Rails: how to order array by associated model characteristic?

Tags: ruby-on-rails, activerecord, associations

I have a user model that has many phone numbers. A phone number belongs to to a phone_type that is created in the database (e.g. office, home, mobile).

phone_type.rb:

```
class PhoneType < ActiveRecord::Base

#  id              :integer          not null, primary key
#  name            :string(255)
#  position        :integer          default(1)

  default_scope :order => 'position ASC'
  default_scope where(:active => true)
```

I've been trying to write an ActiveRecord query that displays the phone numbers for a user, but in an order that's determined by the order set for the phone_types by phone_type.position.

My old code is:

```
<% @phones.each do |p| %>
    <%= p.phone_type.name %> <%= p.value %> <br/>
<% end %>
```

But just displays phone numbers by table id order. What's the correct way to write the more complex query?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Try this:

```
@phones = Phone.all(:include => :phone_type)  #To avoid N+1 queries

<% @phones.sort_by{|p| p.phone_type.position}.each do |p| %>
  <%= p.phone_type.name %>
  <%= p.value %> <br/>
<% end %>
```

Comment: Just curious since I'm not 100% clear - why are you getting Phone.all instead of just the one user whose phones are being displayed? Wouldn't you want something like `@some_user.phones`?